# Spacer Item in QML Layouts

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I want to create a layout in `QML` and I'd like to add a spacer item (the bottom selected item from the image below) just as you do using widgets like so:

[image]

But I couldn't find anything to suit this on the `QtQuick` side of things...is it possible to have this kind of layout in `QML` w/o using the anchoring system?
I'd prefer the layouts approach...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give specific spacing to items in a QML layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587755/how-to-give-specific-spacing-to-items-in-a-qml-layout)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can simply use an `Item` with `Layout.fillHeight: true` :

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Button {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: "PushButton"
        }
        Button {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: "PushButton"
        }
        Label {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: "TextLabel"
        }
        Item {
            // spacer item
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; color: "#ffaaaa" } // to visualize the spacer
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

EDIT: Alternatively here, you could have used a `Column` with no spacer item since a `Column` just positions its children from top to bottom and don't spread them to take all the available space.

Comment: I think this is the way to go and it doesn't really smell like workaround! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For those coming from Qt widgets and for comparison: the intended solution in QML for this situation is the [anchoring system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#anchors-prop) that the question mentions. In this case, it would look as follows, and I think it's not so bad :)

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    ColumnLayout {
        // anchors.fill sets all four directional anchors.
        // Loosening one yields the space at the bottom.
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.bottom: undefined

        // Alternative approach: only set the three anchors we want.
//      anchors.top: parent.top
//      anchors.left: parent.left
//      anchors.right: parent.right

        Button {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: "PushButton"
        }
        Button {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: "PushButton"
        }
        Label {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: "TextLabel"
        }
    }
}
```