# QML stack ColumnLayout children on top of each other?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm new to QML, so I may be asking something obvious. I'm struggling to stack elements in ColumnLayout on top of each other. There's just too much spacing between them I can't do anything about. See screenshot for more details:

[image]

Here's the actual QML:

```
ColumnLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 0

    Rectangle {
        color: "blue"
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        height: 50
    }

    Rectangle {
        color: "red"
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        height: 50
    }

    Rectangle {
        color: "yellow"
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        height: 50
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to have the rectangles aligned top to bottom and have spacing between them maybe 2-3 pixels.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35587755/2538363) question?

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo I would certainly consider that a better solution in general than the accepted answer.

Comment: @Mitch Well, there's also *another* duplicate questio/answer with the exact same words by Grecko (couldn't find it) so yeah, it's the "accepted way". Also, having `margins` and `alignment` properties in any `Layout` does seems to collide with the answer statement that "layouts good thing if you don't need to manage positions".

Comment: I think you are right, this is a dupe, but the other answer needs a tidy up, I will post a comment there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give specific spacing to items in a QML layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587755/how-to-give-specific-spacing-to-items-in-a-qml-layout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will works fine if you remove the filling to parent and place there filling just to width

```
anchors.left: parent.left
anchors.right: parent.right
```

After that the code will looks like this

```
ColumnLayout {
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    spacing: 2 //spacing between items in layout
    Rectangle {
        color: "blue"
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        height: 50
    }
    Rectangle {
    ...
    }
    Rectangle {
    ...
    }
}
```

By doing this, you will give to `ColumnLayout` rights to manage himself's `height`. Its height will related to its children's height and will not be stretched to the parent.

Another way is to manage items through `anchor`

```
Item {
  id: item1
}
Item {
  id: item2
  anchor.top: item1.bottom
  anchor.topMargin: 2 
}
Item {
  id: item3
  anchor.top: item2.bottom
  anchor.topMargin: 3 
}
```

Layouts good thing if you don't need to manage positions of items **in specific way** inside layout.

Also it would be helpful to you to check this [Use Case - Positioners and Layouts In QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-usecase-layouts.html)

Comment: This works for the questioners specified use, but still does not teach them the correct way to use a ColumnLayout. Layouts in QML are a handy and powerful thing once mastered. Perhaps you can also provide the correct way of achieving  the questioners aim by using a ColumnLayout, so that the two options can be compared. It is not right to simply claim that one approach is better than the other